# How to interrupt webpack build process?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I've got webpack2 with dev-server bundling continuously with each file change. If the bundle is big, usually it takes about 4-5sec to build it.

So, if I change a file, webpack triggers this 4-5sec build process. If I make any changes in this period, the build process never stops but waits for the finish, and then starts a new one for fresh changes.

Is there a way to interrupt build process, so that new changes start new build process and kill running one?

Comment: Can you show your webpack config file please?

Comment: I think this is too much time for webpack recompilation. Do you use [`CommonsChunkPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) to create separate chunks of your code (so webpack won't recompile all the code, but only needed chunks)?

Comment: @GProst nope, i've already thought about that, yeah..

Comment: @GProst btw, it drastically improved the build time, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)